# Сообщить разработчикам

Tags: java, android

Во многих приложения есть такая кнопка, сообщить разработчикам на экран выводится приложения работающие с электронной почтой как такое сделать?[image: Что-то на подобие этого]

Comment: это называется неявным интентом, подробнее можно прочесть здесь:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/intent.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот пример вывода на экран приложений, работающих конкретно с электронной почтой:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

String title = getResources().getString(R.string.choose_dialog_title);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Comment: добавляю в проект ничего не происходит

Comment: @Zlatan, а если заменить `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` на `Intent.ACTION_SEND`?

Comment: Все ровно Ничего

Comment: @Zlatan, также возможно, что у вас на телефоне просто нет устройств, работающих с почтой - попробуйте заменить `ACTION_SEND` на `ACTION_DIAL` - должно показать приложения для набора номера, оно должно быть точно на телефоне

Comment: Номер открывается, есть gmail и Эл.Почта приложения

Comment: @Zlatan, а если добавить `intent.setType("text/plain");` после создания `intent`?

Comment: Send заработало но sendto пишет ни одно приложение не может выполнять эти действия